# Has the Debian kernel been modified and Linux From Scratch FAQ not been updated?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, lfs

I was building an [LFS (Linux From Scratch)](https://linuxfromscratch.org) system, and up until now, there have been absolutely no errors. However, when installing the "expect" package, `make test` errored out with:
`The system has no more ptys. Ask your system administrator to create more.`
According to the [LFS FAQ](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/faq.html#no-ptys), to fix this error:

> If you do have a .config file, look inside it for the following 2 options:
> `CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS=y CONFIG_DEVPTS_FS=y`
> If either of these has 'n' instead of 'y', then change it and recompile the kernel.
> If they both have 'y', then you probably will not have to recompile the kernel.

My kernel .config file doesn't even have the `CONFIG_DEVPTS_FS=y` line!
 When I attempt to recompile the kernel *with* that line, `make deb-pkg` simply removes the  `CONFIG_DEVPTS_FS=y` line.  Running all the other commands on that FAQ page didn't do anything. Has the Debian kernel been updated and LFS FAQ not? I'm running Debian-kernel 5.10.0-16-amd64. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope this helps https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/regarding-the-system-has-no-more-no-more-ptys-error-in-lfs-7-5-a-4175499404/ Google CONFIG_DEVPTS_FS

Answer (score 1):

The OP figured this out and indicated the solution in a comment (on a now-deleted answer): they needed to mount the PTS filesystem in their chroot.